# FlatList not showing its data React Native

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

Hi guys I am trying to display data from an object to my flatlist here it is

```
import {ItemLists} from '../data/ItemLists';

const ListItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View style={{margin: 10}}>
          <Image source={{
            uri: item.uri,
          }}
          style={{width:200,height:200}}
          resizeMode="cover"
          />
          <Text style={{margin:5}}>{item.text}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  };
```

and here's my dummy data

```
export const ItemLists = [
    {
        title: 'Hot Deals',
        data: [
            {
                "key": 1,
                "text": "Title of Food",
                "uri": "../../Assets/Images/featured-restau-01"
            },
            {
                "key": 2,
                "text": "Title of Food",
                "uri": "../../Assets/Images/featured-restau-02"
            },
            {
                "key": 3,
                "text": "Title of Food",
                "uri": "../../Assets/Images/featured-restau-03"
            },
            {
                "key": 4,
                "text": "Title of Food",
                "uri": "../../Assets/Images/featured-restau-04"
            },
            {
                "key": 5,
                "text": "Title of Food",
                "uri": "../../Assets/Images/featured-restau-05"
            },
            {
                "key": 6,
                "text": "Title of Food",
                "uri": "../../Assets/Images/featured-restau-06"
            },
            {
                "key": 7,
                "text": "Title of Food",
                "uri": "../../Assets/Images/featured-restau-07"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Now here's how I use my `FlatLis`

```
<ScrollView>
//... other codes
//... other codes

<View style={styles.HotDealsContainer}>
      <View style={styles.HotDealItemContainer}>
           <Text style={styles.HotDealTitle}>Hot Deals</Text>
           <View style={styles.HotDealsItem}>
                  <FlatList
                    horizontal 
                    data={ItemLists}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem item {...item}/>}
                  />
          </View>
     </View>
</View>
</ScrollView>


HotDealsContainer:{
    width:'100%',
    height:200,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  HotDealItemContainer:{
    marginTop: -135,
    marginLeft: 20,
    width:Dimensions.get('window').width / 2 * 2 - 40,
    height:150,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  HotDealsItem:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    flexDirection:'row',
  },
  HotDealTitle:{
    color:'#000',
    fontSize:18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
```

The current problem I am facing right now is that it won't display a single thing on the screen . Can someone point out what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ItemLists has only one item which has **title** and data **array**. If you want to render that data you have to pass only that array:

```
            <FlatList
                horizontal 
                data={ItemLists[0].data}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
                renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem item {...item}/>}
              />
```

The second problem I noticed is that you don't pass the item property to . What you want to do is next:

```
<ListItem item={item} />
```

It will be better for readability purpose to store that array of data in a separate variable rather than in an object which is in another array

Comment: before I posted I have tried doing this but still it is not displaying anything on the screen .

Comment: oh geez , It was because of the height and width that's why I couldn't see any .